# Does spring oxm creates singleton jaxbcontext?

Tags: spring, jaxb2, spring-oxm

Inside Spring OXM framework how does `JAXBContext.newInstance()` creates. Is it a singleton or multiple instance. My requirement is I want singleton `jaxbcontext` object? Please share Spring OXM details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it's creating singleton jaxb context internally inside `Jaxb2Marshaller`, like this:

```
    public JAXBContext getJaxbContext() {
            if (this.jaxbContext != null) {
                return this.jaxbContext;
            }
            synchronized (this.jaxbContextMonitor) {
                if (this.jaxbContext == null) {
                    try {
                        if (StringUtils.hasLength(this.contextPath)) {
                            this.jaxbContext = createJaxbContextFromContextPath();
                        }
                        else if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(this.classesToBeBound)) {
                            this.jaxbContext = createJaxbContextFromClasses();
                        }
                        else if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(this.packagesToScan)) {
                            this.jaxbContext = createJaxbContextFromPackages();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JAXBException ex) {
                        throw convertJaxbException(ex);
                    }
                }
                return this.jaxbContext;
            }
        }
```